# C++ - Avoiding multiple if statements for managing errors

Tags: c++, if-statement, coding-style

Simple question.

I have this code in front of me:

```
if ( somethings() == false ) {
    log("error when ...somethings()");
    return false;
}
// do somethings
if ( somethings2() == false ) {
    log("error when ...somethings2()");
    return false;
}
// ...
// eventually
if ( somethingsN() == false ) {
    log("error when ...somethingsN()");
    delete myData;
    return false;
}
```

Not sexy, right ? What would be the best method(/pattern ?) for improving this code ?

### Solution 1:

I was wondering about using exceptions

```
try {
    if ( somethings() == false )
        throw std::runtime_error("error when ...somethings()");
    // do somethings
    if ( somethings2() == false )
        throw std::runtime_error("error when ...somethings2()");
    // ...
    if ( somethingsN() == false )
        throw std::runtime_error("error when ...somethingsN()");
}
catch ( std::exception& e ) {
    log(e.what());
    delete myData;
    return false;
}
```

### Solution 2:

Using nested if statements

```
if ( somethings() ) {
    // do somethings...
    if ( somethings1() ) {
        // ... (eventually too many indent)
        if ( somethingsN() ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
delete myData;
return false;
```

What are your methods ?
I just want to improve my coding style here.

#### Note (edit)

"Do not use 'delete', use smart pointers instead such as unique_ptr" (thanks all)

Comment: `Nested if` will not produce the same results

Comment: I like your original code. ;P

Comment: Why are your somethings not throwing directly? It looks rather odd that you combine "success flags" returned by methods with exceptions. Another solution is to write a macro or much better a template function that checks the call and throws. Edit: Your original code is bad in terms of a centralized logging, you are repeating text here so I do not agree with @Galik

Comment: Don't say `delete`. Use a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Additionally: `myData` is out of context it is not clear whether somethingN has produced it or whether it must be deleted during a clean. Anyway I would prefer using smart pointers here. `delete myData` is error prone. Edit: I second @KerrekSB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw an exception on error rather than returning a magic value for the caller to check; avoid dynamic allocation except when you really need it; use smart pointers or other RAII types to manage it when you really do. Then the code becomes rather more straightforward:

```
somethings();
somethings2();
// ...
somethingsN();
```

Comment: nice ! (we can not make it more simpler :-) So, it seems this is a concept that must be applied to the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define CHECK(x) \
  do { if (!(x)) throw MyException(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__); } while(0)

try {
  // call third-party or 
  // C functions that don't throw
  CHECK(thisone());
  CHECK(thatone());
  CHECK(theotherone());
  // call my own functions
  anotherone(); // throws
  yetanotherone(); // throws
} catch (std::exception& e) {
  log(e.what());
}
```

And of course no `delete`. `unique_ptr` is your friend.